# Springboot - packaging issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a springboot app which runs fine from the IDE (IntelliJ) but does not run when I copy the boot jar into a different clean folder (in windows).

The error I get is as follows:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:104)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry n.properties not found in .\cef-fulltext-updater-exec.jar
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:89)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
        at com.elsevier.cef.fulltext.updater.configuration.FulltextUpdaterApplication.main(FulltextUpdaterApplication.java:10)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry n.properties not found in .\cef-fulltext-updater-exec.jar
```

Strangely I do not get this error when I run with the same jar file in linux ec2 instance.

Why would this happen?

p.s. I have tried several things but its taking me in various random paths which do not seem to answer this basic question.

Comment: You didn't package the executable JAR properly.  Spring Boot cannot find that n.properties file.  I'm betting your code tries to load it as if it had access to the file system.  You should load it as a resource stream from the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @duffymo thanks for your response. How does it then work in ec2? I am very curious on why would it be any different on ec2

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a Maven project.  IntelliJ is smart enough to be able to do it b/c it knows about the file system.  EC2 only knows about your package.  Different animal.

Comment: yes it is maven project. Also it actually works on EC2 but not in windows in a different folder!! :)